# C++ undefined reference to method

Tags: c++, methods, reference, header, undefined

I am new to C++ and am attempting to define an object class that gives the ability to do large number arithmetic, utilizing a string as the internal structure for the number.  One of the arithmetic methods I am attempting to utilize is addition, by overloading the '+' operator and utilizing a helper method called add(string a, string b) that I have defined.  However, when I compile with g++, I receive this error message: undefined reference to huge_number::add collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.  I've searched around quite a bit to try and determine the problem but have yet to find the solution.  If someone could please help, I imagine the solution is quite simple and I am just missing it for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string add (string a, string b)
```

you are forgetting class name specifier for `add` in your .cpp:

```
string huge_number::add (string a, string b)
```